# Getting parameter from hierarchical block LTSpice

Tags: ltspice, simulation, design, spice

I know how to pass parameters *into* a block, but I can't figure out how to get parameters back out.

For example, I'm passing params into a block with:
[image: passing parameters to a hierarchical block]

Within the block, these parameters are used to calculate a parameter that is used by *both* the hierarchal block *and* the main schematic. I tried accessing this parameter with {x1.param} to no avail, and haven't been able to find a method to do this.

Is there a way to access a parameter from a sub-block, or do I need to define the equation set on both schematics?

---

Edit: Thanks for the answers guys. It looks like this is not possible.

From **a concerned citizen**:
*Hierarchical blocks are local scopes, that is, variables and functions that are defined inside the block/subcircuit are not visible to the outside world. Think of it as a black box: what happens inside, stays inside, unless you provide a way from inside to outside -- and the only way you can do that is with a pin.*

Comment: Can't you just use .FUNC in this case? We'd need to see a lot more detail to provide good advice. If you are asking for a way that a .SUBCKT can return something to a calling .SUBCKT or top level schematic, I can say I don't know of a way right now. But perhaps if you discuss more detail, alternatives in this case might be offered.

Comment: Parameters are supposed to characterize a specific instance of a sub-block.  This is true in other areas of electronics, such as Verilog modules.  The only way I know how to get data out of an instance is via its output pins.  So you could technically make an extra output pin tied to a DC voltage source spitting out a value evaluated to your expression.  Then you have access to this number in the main schematic but can only use it with B-sources which can reference live circuit nodes.  It's janky, but that's the only way I can think of.

Comment: What @SteKulov is true: the subcircuits, or hierarchical blocks are local scopes, that is, variables and functions that are defined inside the block/subcircuit are not visible to the outside world. Think of it as a black box: what happens inside, stays inside, *unless* you provide a way from inside to outside -- and the only way you can do that is with a pin.